# Finding regions of interest in image/radio data heatmap

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have this weird 'image' data. It's not really an image, it's more like radio waves/signals. But it can be considered an 'image' for python/opencv purposes. It has dimensions 100x100x3 (100x100 size and 3 channels similar to RGB in an image). As you can see, the 'pixel' values are very small (order of magnitude of 10^-12). The rightmost image is normalised with all 3 channels.

I have a set of labels, which you can see marked as 'X'. These are what I'm trying to predict/find in these images. I was curious to know of what approaches might work well for this task. I'm wondering if I should explore approaches like clustering/dbscan or deep learning methods using the 'X' locations as target variables? The reason I am worried about deep learning approaches is that I can't afford any false positives, and there's only 1000 of these images to train on. Any insight (and even code/answers!) would be much appreciated.

[image]

Here is an example of what an original image looks like, which can be read in with opencv:

```
im = cv2.imread('image_data.png')
cv2.imshow('frame', im)
```

[image]

Comment: Post an original image without the X marks and without the scales and heat map colormap.  What have you tried?  Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: channel 1 looks like local maxima (with lowpasses and thresholds) would solve this trivially. channel 2 and 3 appear to be derivatives wrt x and y, you might be able to use that added info... unless that's merely calculated from channel 1. -- you really should find a way to post sample data. the plots help get your point across but people need data to experiment with. -- any DL/AI approach would merely result in a model that finds local maxima. I see no more patterns than that here.

Comment: @fmw42 hello, I've added an original image, which you can save and read using the code provided above.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz channel 1 seems to solve it in most cases. However there are some cases where the 'X' are aligned with the minima with the other channels and not with channel 1. However, it always seems to be aligned with the RGB representation, so maybe combining all channels works best? 

I have updated the question with sample data.

Comment: I see trouble with those blobs being too close together to distinguish them easily. a careful lowpass/median filter brings them out a little more. such data might require a "mixture of gaussians" approach.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yea the ones close together are difficult to solve. But what's really annoying me right now is the treatment of pixel values. The original 'image' has pixel values in 10^-12 range. Do you know if I need to normalise it to 0-1 or 0-255? And also what datatypes (float, int). Sometimes I try certain ranges/datatypes and then it doesn't get displayed properly by opencv/matplotlib.

Comment: You might consider using TIFF format which can store floats.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I’ve already got the data loaded in numpy array as float. Just wondering what range I should use for processing

Comment: if an API requires integers, scale accordingly. if it takes floats... keep them as is, or scale, should make no difference.